# "Poem" tag for poems that aren't riddles

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags

I've recently written [more](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/20245/a-crumbled-jumbled-poem) than [one](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/20380/a-wonderfully-poor-poem) puzzle in the form of a poem, neither of which I would really classify as "riddles". There are plenty of others that I've seen (a few more recently than others) that follow along this same pattern. I'm hesitant to add a tag though, because I've seen new tags with 1 or 2 associated questions be purged pretty quickly. My questions here are twofold:

1. Is it okay to add a new tag like this without discussion (moot now, but I'm still curious), or is it frowned upon?
2. Is there enough of a distinction between puzzles set in the form of a poem and puzzles set in the form of a riddle to merit adding a new tag here?

Answer (score 3):

Tags come and tags go, 
Dead leaves fall through smoky air. 
Create it and see.

Comment: Haikus FTW! Amazing :-D

Answer (score 2):

1. I think this is **fine**. You need a certain amount of rep in order to create new tags, but as a Trusted User you'll have no problem with that. New tags aren't deleted unless they're *meta-tags* (see [here](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/)) or *obviously silly* (I once created a [leoll2](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/leoll2) tag as a joke), or there's clear community consensus to get rid of them (e.g. see [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2920/should-we-burninate-the-brainteaser-tag)).
2. There's already a much-used [rhyme](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rhyme) tag, for puzzles (not necessarily riddles) "written in rhyme for an artistic twist". Given this precedent, there should be no problem with creating a [poem](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/poem) tag.

As an aside, I think the second puzzle you link to *is* a riddle, since the answer will specify the "I" being referred to throughout. It's not a single object but one that gets transformed; however, there's still something unknown being referred to cryptically, which is the hallmark of a riddle.

Answer (score 1):

Bailey, i was actually looking for a poem/poetry tag today, for a poem that is also a riddle and also comes under wordplay. Definitely need a poetry tag.